# Can't compress a recycled bitmap - java.lang.IllegalStateException error

Tags: android

I am getting the below error in the logcat and the app crashes. I tried many ways but nothing seems to be working. So looking forward for suggestion.

```
Process: com.dragedy.playermusic.debug, PID: 8073
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
                                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:346)
                                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1005)
                                                                                     at com.dragedy.playermusic.lyricspack.services.NotificationListenerService.saveArtwork(NotificationListenerService.java:401)
                                                                                     at com.dragedy.playermusic.lyricspack.services.NotificationListenerService.onClientMetadataUpdate(NotificationListenerService.java:382)
                                                                                     at android.media.RemoteController.onNewMetadata(RemoteController.java:802)
                                                                                     at android.media.RemoteController.access$900(RemoteController.java:56)
                                                                                     at android.media.RemoteController$EventHandler.handleMessage(RemoteController.java:684)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the function in which I am getting the error.

```
  private void saveArtwork(Bitmap artwork, String artist, String track, boolean isPlaying) {
        File artworksDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "artworks");
        if (artwork != null && (artworksDir.exists() || artworksDir.mkdir())) {
            File artworkFile = new File(artworksDir, artist + track + ".png");
            if (!artworkFile.exists())
                try {
                    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                    artworkFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            if (artworkFile.length() == 0 || !artwork.sameAs(lastBitmap)) { //prevent many writes of the same Bitmap
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                artwork.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(artworkFile);
                    stream.writeTo(fos);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fos != null)
                        {
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.getFD().sync();
                            fos.close();
                        }
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }



            if (lastBitmap != null)
            {

                lastBitmap.recycle();
            }
            lastBitmap = artwork;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already called recycle on the bitmap.  Recycled bitmaps have all their memory freed, so they cannot be compressed (they've already forgotten their data).  Look for calls to recycle in your code or any library you're using and try to figure out why its been called/if it needs to be removed/if you can compress before then.